# HIVE equivalent of FIRST and LAST

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, hiveql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
table1: ID, CODE, RESULT, RESULT2, RESULT3
```

I have this SAS code:

```
data table1
   set table1;
   BY ID, CODE;
   IF FIRST.CODE and RESULT='A' THEN OUTPUT;
   ELSE IF LAST.CODE and RESULT NE 'A' THEN OUTPUT;
RUN;
```

So we are grouping the data by ID and CODE, and then writing to the dataset if certain conditions are met. I want to write a hive query to replicate this. This is what I have:

```
proc sql;
   create table temp as
   select *, row_number() over (partition by ID, CODE) as rowNum
   from table1;

   create table temp2 as
   select a.ID, a.CODE, a.RESULT, a.RESULT2, a.RESULT3
   from temp a
   inner join (select ID, CODE, max(rowNum) as maxRowNum
               from temp
               group by ID, CODE) b
     on a.ID=b.ID and a.CODE=b.CODE
   where (a.rowNum=1 and a.RESULT='A') or (a.rowNum=b.maxRowNum and a.RESULT NE 'A');
quit;
```

There are two issues I see with this.

1) The row that is first or last in each BY group is entirely dependant on the order of rows in table1 in SAS, we aren't ordering by anything. I don't think row order is preserved when translating to a hive query.

2) The SAS code is taking the first row in each BY GROUP or the last, not both. I think that my HIVE query is taking both, resulting in more rows than I want.

Any suggestions or insight on how to improve my query is appreciated. Is it even possible to replicate this SAS code in HIVE?

Comment: there is a `first_value()` and `last_value()` function in hive https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Comment: there is `min()` and `max()` even for strings when using `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

The SAS code has a `by` statement (`BY ID CODE;`), which tells SAS that the `set` dataset is sorted at those levels. So, not a random selection for `first.` and `last.`.

That said, we can replicate this in HIVE by using the `first_value` and `last_value` window functions.

`FIRST.CODE` should replicate to

```
first_value(code) over (partition by Id order by code)fcode
```

Similarly, `LAST.CODE` would be

```
last_value(code) over (partition by Id order by code)lcode
```

Once you have the `fcode` and `lcode` columns, use case when statements for the `result` column criteria. Like,

```
case when (code=fcode and result='A') or (code=lcode and result<>'A')
then 1 else 0 end as op_flag
```

Then the fetch the table with `where op_flag = 1`

**SAMPLE**

```
select id, code, result from (
select *,
first_value(code) over (partition by id order by code)fcode,
last_value(code) over (partition by id order by code)lcode
from footab) f
where (code=fcode and result='A') or (code=lcode and result<>'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding point 1) the BY group processing requires the input data to be sorted or indexed on BY variables, so though the code contains no ordering, the source data is processed in order. If the input data was not indexed/sorted, SAS will throw error.
Regarding this, possible differences are on rows with same values of BY variables, especially if the RESULT is different.
In SAS, I would pre-sort data by ID, CODE, RESULT, then use BY ID CODE in order to not be influenced by order of rows.

Regarding 2) FIRST and LAST can be both true in SAS. Since your condition for first and last on RESULT is different, I guess this is not a source of differences.

I guess you could add another field as

```
row_number() over (partition by ID, CODE desc) as rowNumDesc
```

to detect last row with rowNumDesc =  1 (so that you skip the join).

> EDIT:

I think the two programs above both include random selection of rows for groups with same values of ID and CODE variables, especially with same values of RESULT. But you should get same number of rows from both. If not, just debug it.

However the random aspect in SAS code/storage is based on physical order of rows, while the ROW_NUMBERs randomness within a group will be influenced by the implementation of the function in the engine.

Comment: So as the SAS code is in the OP, is it possible to replicate this in hive or sql? Because if there is a tie, I'm thinking SAS will select the literal "last" row in the group, whereas in hive/sql it would probably be randomly selected? @vasja